# Mnemonic for ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

How can we add [mnemonics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/190kw3at%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for `ComboBox`?

For example, in a `CheckBox`, in the caption we can say '`Check&BoxCaption`', notice the '&' before 'B'. In the form, this 'B' gets underlined and we can access it by pressing Alt+B (as a keyboard shortcut).

But how do we do this in case of `ComboBox`?

[image: Check mnemonic implemented on Visual Studio Options page in a label against a ComboBox]
Check mnemonic implemented on Visual Studio Options page in a label against a `ComboBox`

I am guessing (checking the screenshot above), we create a mnemonic in the label against the `ComboBox`.
How do we link it to the `ComboBox`, in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The control itself does not support a hotkey. This is handled through label controls. Since labels cannot have the focus, selecting a label will give the focus to the next control in the tab order.

So add a label control to your form and give it a hotkey by inserting the '&' character before the hotkey character. Make sure the label control has a tab index value that is one less than your combo box so that the combobox is the next control in the tab order after the label.

This is the same way it works for other controls as well, such as text boxes and other lists.

Comment: thanks..but how do we 'give the combobox a label' ?? sorry if my question was not clear.

Comment: Please see the update to my answer to make it a little more clear.

Comment: Just for my own edification, are you saying that the label is associated with the combobox strictly based on its relative tab index? I only ask because that seems so.. bizarre.

Comment: Yes. That's how it works. Labels cannot get the focus so the focus goes to the next control in the tab order.

Comment: I see. So it's not that the label is "associated" with the combobox, it's more of a hack. You can't create a mnemonic for a combobox directly, so instead you create a mnemonic for a thing that can't receive focus and make sure the next thing is line is the combobox. Again, very bizarre, but then again WinForms isn't the most brilliant of toolkits. Thanks for helping me learn something new.

Comment: Well, it's not entirely a hack. This is the way it was designed to work since before the early days of Windows. It's the way that you access controls via hotkeys when the control does not support hotkeys. I've reworked my answer to hopefully make it a bit more clear.

Comment: this works amazingly well on WinForms and thanks for your explanation. Cheers.